Simplifying an inequality by omitting a parameter
The answer to my question might be a clear "No", is there an equivalent way to write the following inequality in which we do not need the parameter $n$?
$$\frac{1}{2} \pi  (2 n+1)<a<\frac{1}{2} \pi  (2 n+3)\land \frac{1}{2} \pi  (2 n+1)<b<\frac{1}{2} \pi  (2 n+3)\land n\in
   \mathbb{Z}$$
This can be considered similar to the situation when we write $x=r \cos (\theta )\land y=r \sin (\theta )$ as $x^2+y^2=r^2$ by omitting $\theta$.
Thanks for any comments.

I think $\lfloor \frac{a}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\rfloor =\lfloor \frac{b}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$ works.
Reasoning: make $n$ the subject of the left hand side to get $$n<\frac{a}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}<n+1$$ and the same for $b$. The requirement that it should be the same $n$ for each means the integer parts are equal.
Note that this gives non-strict inequalities at the lower end: $\frac{1}{2}\pi(2n+1) \le a$. If this matters, you will need to add the conditions that $\frac{a}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{b}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}$ are not integers.

This is fantastic. Seems to work for the values I tried. Thanks a lot. Could you please add your rough reasoning on how you came up with this? Also, it would be helpful if you could look at this as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4919433/1322804. I have a bunch of this type of inequalities in which I need to find the equivalent inequalities.
