Omitting a parameter from an inequality
Could someone help in omitting the parameter $n$ (represents an odd integer) from this inequality? I need to find an equivalent inequality in which $n$ is absent.
$$\frac{c_1}{c_2-n \pi }\neq \frac{c_3}{-n \pi +c_4}\land \frac{1+n}{2}\in \mathbb{Z}$$
$c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, $c_4$ are real numbers and the following restrictions on them: $\left(c_1>0\land c_3<0\right)\lor \left(c_1<0\land c_3>0\right), c_2\neq \pi  n, c_4\neq \pi  n$ ($n$ same as above).
This is similar to:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4919200/1322804
Thanks

Actually I need to do for the following, but I guess the above is a simpler form: $\frac{\Im(a)}{2 \Re(a)-\pi  n}\neq \frac{\Im(b)}{2 \Re(b)-\pi  n}\land n\neq 0\land \frac{n+1}{2}\in \mathbb{Z}$

I'm not sure I completely understand, but if the goal is to just rewrite the inequality so that it doesn't contain $n$, this can be done in many ways, for example $\cos^{-1}(-1)$ and ${n\pi \mid n \text{ is odd}}$ coincide, so you could have in the denominators $c_i-a$, where $a\in\cos^{-1}(-1)$ for $i=2,4$. Also, the $c_i$ can't be any real number, we must have $c_2, c_4\neq n\pi$ for all integers $n$.

@Randy, sorry for not being clear. I needed something which is explicitly or implicitly free from $n$. Not sure if I still make sense :) however I got what I needed and posted an answer myself.

I solved it myself, thanks to anyone who worked on it.
Here is the equivalent inequality without $n$:
$$2 \pi  \left\lceil \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{c_2
   c_3-c_1 c_4}{c_1 \pi -c_3 \pi
   }+1\right)\right\rceil +\frac{c_1 c_4-c_2
   c_3}{c_1-c_3}\neq \pi$$
Derivation: solve for $n$ from the original inequality. since $n$ is an odd integer, $(n-1)/2$ is an integer. So it should satisfy $\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor =\frac{n-1}{2}$. Simplifying and changing the equality to inequality gives the above solution.

Take $c_3=0$ and $c_4=-\pi$. Then $\frac{c_2c_3-c_1c_4}{c_1\pi-c_3\pi} = \frac{c_1\pi}{c_1\pi} = 1$. Therefore the first term is $2\pi$. The second term is $\frac{c_1c_4-c_2c_3}{c_1-c_3}=\frac{-c_1\pi}{c_1}=-\pi$. Together this gives $\pi \neq \pi$. It seems that some information was lost because the original inequality prevents $c_4=-\pi$ as a choice, or there is a typo in your conversion (I haven't checked for that myself).

Thanks for pointing this out. I should have added some additional conditions in my original post: $c_1\neq 0, c_3\neq 0, c_2\neq \pi  n, c_4\neq \pi  n$ ($n$ is odd). Updated the original post.

There is still something off because this inequality implies $c_1\neq c_3$ but that is not the case with the original inequality. Take $c_1=c_3=1$ and $c_2=2$, $c_4=1$. This satisfies the original inequality, but not the conversion.

Hmm, you are right. I went back to my original problem and realized that some more restrictions apply. Updated the post accordingly.
